# Getting permission error when application hosted in iis?

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration

I am using iis version 6.2 . I hosted the ASP.NET application.When i load the hosted link in browser getting **HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**.Error code: 0x80070003,Config error:Cannot read configuration file.I gave permission for IUSR to web.config file.Please suggest your solution.

Comment: sounds like something is incorrect in one of your .config files. There is very little info to go on here though so it's hard to say

Comment: @Jeremy:Do you need more info to find?.Please say what are the info needed?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this issue. Actually in my web.config file authentication mode set as "Forms".I disabled the Form authentication in iis that is the problem. When i enabled it was working. When we host in iis have to give permission for web.config and enable the authentication(Windows/Forms).